# get keys from values exists in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, key, key-value-store

I have a key value pairs. I want to find a key of values exists in a dataframe and assign those key as new column.

For e.g I have a dictionary

```
 "low" : [1,4] "high" : [2,5] "medium":[3]

c1 
1  
2  
3  
4  
5
```

and expecting output like this

```
c1 c2
1  low
2  high
3  medium
4  low
5  high
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), but first generate dictionary in dict comprehension with `split`, also convert column `c1` to `string` if filled by integers:

```
d = {"low" : '1,4', "high" : '2,5', "medium":'3'}

d1 = {x:k for k, v in d.items() for x in v.split(',')}
print (d1)
{'1': 'low', '4': 'low', '2': 'high', '5': 'high', '3': 'medium'}

df['c2'] = df['c1'].astype(str).map(d1)
print (df)
   c1      c2
0   1     low
1   2    high
2   3  medium
3   4     low
4   5    high
```

Solution if lists in `dictionary`:

```
d = {"low" : [1,4], "high" : [2,5], "medium":[3]}

d1 = {x:k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
print (d1)
{1: 'low', 4: 'low', 2: 'high', 5: 'high', 3: 'medium'}

df['c2'] = df['c1'].map(d1)
print (df)
   c1      c2
0   1     low
1   2    high
2   3  medium
3   4     low
4   5    high
```

Comment: i got following error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' @jezrael

Comment: sorry.. but now all the values got mapped to one key.

Comment: @sara - Maybe main problem is I have to guess format of dictionary, `"low" : 1,4 "high" : 2,5 "medium":3` is not valid, can you add valid dict to quation?

Comment: @sara - Thanks, can you show output of my solution in question? For me working nice.

Comment: This is the dictionary i have.. dictionary = {}
dictionary["low"] = list1
dictionary["high"] = list2
dictionary['medium'] = list3
dictionary['normal'] = list4    and when i applied your function, all the values got mapped to normal...

Comment: @sara - So if use `d = {"low" : list1, "high" : list2, "medium":list3}` instead `d = {"low" : [1,4], "high" : [2,5], "medium":[3]}`  working my second solution?

Comment: no its not working.. if i use first solution, list object has no attribute 'split.. and for second solution all the values got mapped to normal...

Comment: @sara - One idea, how working change `df['c2'] = df['c1'].map(d1)` to `df['c2'] = df['c1'].astype(str).map(d1)` ?

Comment: does that change values? coz if i print d1,  all values got mapped to normal.. how does that change after mapping?

Comment: @sara - It was idea if is necessary change column values to strings. But if still not working I guess some data related probl;em.

Comment: @sara - Are data confidental?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209561/discussion-between-sara-and-jezrael).